# R replace() conflict with logical test

Tags: r, replace

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(fruit = c("apple", "pear"), value = c(3, 1))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   fruit value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 apple     3
#> 2 pear      1
```

When I try to replace occurrences of "apple" with "golden apple", everything in the same column turns into "golden apple". Yet my logical specifies that fruit must equal "apple" `(fruit == "apple")`. Is something else wrong? How did my pear turn into a golden apple?

```
df %>% replace(fruit == "apple", "golden apple")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   fruit        value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 golden apple     3
#> 2 golden apple     1
```

If I try within the mutate framework I get an error:

```
df %>% mutate(fruit = replace(fruit == "apple", "golden apple"))
#> Error in replace(fruit == "apple", "golden apple") : 
#>   argument "values" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: try it inside `mutate`

Comment: @akrun `df %>% mutate(fruit = replace(fruit == "apple", "golden apple"))` yields the error `Error in replace(fruit == "apple", "golden apple") : argument "values" is missing, with no default`

Comment: replace(fruit, fruit==

Comment: @akrun that did it. Do you want to answer so I can mark solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `x` and `list` as the logical expression

```
df %>%
    {replace(x = ., list = .== "apple", values = "golden apple")}
```

But, since this is only a single column `fruit` and outside the `mutate/summarise`, we cannot use the unquoted column names, it may need to be extracted `.$fruit`.  However, this can be done within `mutate` and for multiple columns (`mutate_at` or `mutate_if`)

```
df %>% 
     mutate(fruit = replace(fruit, fruit == "apple", "golden apple"))
```